# PHP/Laravel Array diff on nested arrays - remove false values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays that contain nested arrays also, where I want to compare them against each other. If the value in the first array is `false`, I want that key removed from the 2nd array.

1st array: `$arrayOne`:

```php
'entities' => [
        'number' => false,
        'items' => [
            [
               'name' => false, 
            ],
        ],
        'totals' => [
            'gross' => true,
            'tax' => [
                'amount' => true,
            ],
        ]
];
```

Then, I have the second array `$arrayTwo`:

```php
'entities' => [
        'number' => '8000000',
        'items' => [
            [
               'name' => 'Bolt cutter', 
            ],
            [
               'name' => 'Wire cutter', 
            ],
        ],
        'totals' => [
            'gross' => 120.52,
            'tax' => [
                'amount' => 90.21,
            ],
        ]
];
```

As you can see in the first array, the keys: `number` and `items.name` is `false`. These two keys should not be in the final array, thus making it look like this:

```php
'entities' => [
        'items' => [],
        'totals' => [
            'gross' => 120.52,
            'tax' => [],
        ]
];
```

How can I accomplish this with nested arrays? I have managed to do it for the "1st level" of the array using below:

```php
foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $entity) {

       if ($entity === false) {
           unset($arrayTwo[$key]);
       }
}
```

However, as said, this only handles the first level of the array and not the nested array(s).

Comment: Can you post the structure of the final array you are trying to compare? Are they retrieve with Laravel eloquent or Laravel Colleciton? I want to know if there is any underlying method you could use for this.

Comment: The final array is shared in my OP. They are retrieved with Laravel Collection :)

Comment: I mean, does your second array may contain multiple entities? If it's exactly as you said, one of the answer should work. But if you get multiple entities in the second array and each of them need to be filtered, this is another problem.

I tried the first answer work as you asked.
The second one eliminated the tax array, but this could be fix.

So this is why I'm trying to see where is the problem.

Comment: @ElieMorin Ah I see! Yes, the second (and nested array in general) can contain multiple entities - and I guess that is why the first answer does not work (it does work if it doesn't contain multiple entities)

Comment: Well, in that case, you should edit your question so we can be able to help you properly

Comment: I have updated my op

Comment: @oliverbj news for my answer?...

Comment: @Berto99 Sorry, but it does not work (see my updated question)

Comment: @ElieMorin oh. :D i did not see that comming.

Answer (score 2):

i did test this, and it will work fine.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$flattened_array1 = Arr::dot($array1);
$flattened_array2 = Arr::dot($array2);



foreach ($flattened_array1 as $key => $entity) {

   if ($entity === false) {
        // remove all number key from first array
        $filteredKey = preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $key);
        foreach ($flattened_array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if(preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $key2) == $filteredKey){
                // comparing to removed number key version of second array
               unset($flattened_array2[$key2]);
            }
        }
   }
}


// undot the array
$final_array = [];
foreach ($flattened_array2 as $key => $value) {
    array_set($final_array , $key, $value);
}
```

---

new Update to support empty array when nested array

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$flattened_array1 = Arr::dot($array1);
$flattened_array2 = Arr::dot($array2);

// Function to check string starting 

foreach ($flattened_array1 as $key => $entity) {

   if ($entity === false) {
        // remove all number key from first array
        $removerCounter[$key] = 0;
        $filteredKey = preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $key);
        foreach ($flattened_array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            // comparing to removed number key version of second array
            if(preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $key2) == $filteredKey){


                // check if it contain filtered number key then
                if(preg_replace('/[0-9]+\./', '', $key2) != $key2){
                    $currentKey = $key2;
                    preg_match_all("/[0-9]+\./", $currentKey, $hits);
                    if(!isset($hits[0]) || empty($hits[0]) ){
                        break;
                    }

                    $needle = $hits[0] [ count($hits[0]) - 1 ];
                    // it is inside key not at the begining
                    if(stripos($currentKey, $needle) != 0){
                        // if parent key has no child so let it be empty array
                        $parentKey = trim(substr($currentKey, 0, stripos($currentKey, $needle)), '.');

                        // search inside secound array for parentKey of this nested array
                        $searchAndFound = false;
                        foreach ($flattened_array2 as $inner_key2 => $inner_value2) {
                            if( !($searchAndFound) && $inner_key2 != $key2 && Str::startsWith($inner_key2, $parentKey) ) {
                               $searchAndFound = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if( $searchAndFound ){
                            // die("e");
                            unset($flattened_array2[$key2]);
                            $removerCounter[$key]++;
                            //remove this key and go for next key in secound array 
                            continue;
                        }

                        if($removerCounter[$key] > 0){
                            unset($flattened_array2[$key2]);
                        }
                     
                        $flattened_array2[$parentKey] = [];

                    }
                }
                else{
                    unset($flattened_array2[$key2]);
                }
            }
        }
   }
}

// undot the array
$final_array = [];
foreach ($flattened_array2 as $key => $value) {
    array_set($final_array , $key, $value);
}
```

it is more complated that it expected to be . but does the trick :s.

Comment: This does not work if the nested array have multiple items. The dot notation will be: `items.0.name` and `items.1.name` etc.

Comment: ofcourse it must not, you did not mentioned this in your question. let me take a look.

Comment: My apologies! It is not in my original question. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If the ```entities.items.name``` is set to true, does it remove it ?

Comment: @ElieMorin no, the question says only remove item that the are set to false in first array. so i checked entity value if is false then i try to find the keys that are related to this value in second array.

Comment: I tested it, seems nearly perfect solution. The only things is into the op, the items array should be there, but empty. With your solution, the items is removed completly. But hey! for me it's a +1

Comment: @ElieMorin there are some situation that new answer will not work either to create empty array but it is not well explained rule for this question and there is a lot of situation that may happen. so i decided to make it as simple as possible. if there is two numeric array inside then its possible to do a for over all hits and check everyone of them from the last one

Comment: Yeah, i started to write a solution using your code with some condition like ```is_int()``` or ```is_array()```, etc... To create something that can handle more situation. Since your solution is working fine from my perspective, I droped it.